# Циклы C++ в РАЯ

Tags: псевдокод, циклы, c++

Подскажите, как записать такой цикл:

```
for (j1 = 0, j2 = 0, k = 0; (j1 < na || j2 < nb) && k < 2; j1++, j2++) {
    ...
}
```

на псевдокоде или русском алгоритмическом языке?

Полный цикл:

```
for (i = 0; i < na; i++) {
    for (j1 = 0, j2 = 0, k = 0; (j1 < na || j2 < nb) && k < 2; j1++, j2++) {
        if ((a[i] == a[j1] && i != j1) || a[i] == b[j2]) k++;
    }
    if (k == 0)
        c[nc++] = a[i];
}
```

Comment: Не понял, какие вещи, какой псевдокод?

Comment: Исправил вопрос

Comment: так что-ли ? или надо матерно ?

    присвоить i = 0;
    пока i меньше na 
     прибавить i
     присвоить j1 = 0, j2 = 0, k = 0
      пока (j1 меньше na или j2 меньше nb ) и k меньше 2
        прибавить j1 прибавить j2
         если ... то ....  всё
      всё
      если ... то ... всё
    всё
    КОНЕЦ.

у меня вопрос на... зачем это надо ?

Answer (score 3):

[@mad_putin](/users/10333/mad_putin), а зачем в for(... && k < 2; ...)?

Ведь реальные действия (а именно, c[nc++] = a[i]) выполняются **только** для k == 0 ???

Т.е. Вы что-то ищете в этом внутреннем for(...) и только если не нашли, то добавляете a[i] в c[]. Поэтому видимо надо переписать так

```
for (i=0;i<na;i++){
  for (j1=0,j2=0,k=0;j1<na && j2<nb;j1++,j2++){
    if ((a[i]==a[j1] && i!=j1) || a[i]==b[j2]) {
       k++;
       break;
    }
  }
  if (k==0)c[nc++]=a[i];
}
```

Я рискнул заменить `||` на `&&` поскольку предполагаю, что в a[] na элементов, а в b[] nb и Вы хотите обращаться только к существующим.

А на псевдокоде я бы все содержимое внешнего цикла написал так

```
for (i = 0; i < na; i++) {
    Добавим к c[] те a[i], которые не повторяются в a[] и отсутствуют в b[];
}
// теперь в c[] nc элементов
```